# Blank page when printing BufferedImage in Java

Tags: java, printing, bufferedimage

I have the following code to simply print a QR Code, but the printer releases a blank page. Adding text to the graphics works well and gets printed, but not the image. If i uncomment the ImageIO section, the image also gets saved properly.

```
    private BufferedImage printImg;

    public Print(BufferedImage img) {
        try {
            this.printImg = img;

            // ask for print
            PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            if (pjob.printDialog() == false) return;
            pjob.setPrintable(this);

            //File f = new File("MyFile.png");
            //ImageIO.write(printImg, "PNG", f);

            pjob.print();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException {
        if (page > 0)
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        try {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.drawImage(this.printImg, 0, 0, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
```

The original image is a PNG in RGBA and i read it like this:

```
BufferedImage in = ImageIO.read(qr.file());
Print p = new Print(in);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Did you ever get it to work, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be the high resolution of a printer (as opposed to a screen).
As an image is pixel based. That combined with unprintable margins might show nothing.

The following should show something

```
double x = pf.getImageableX();
double y = pf.getImageableY();
double w = pf.getImageableWidth();
double h = pf.getImageableHeight();
g2.drawImage(printImg, x, y, w, h, null);
```

And from there to real proportional scaling is a matter of calculation.
You might like to set `RenderingHints`.